# MySQL database-performance based on useramount

Tags: .net, mysql, performance

I am trying to figure out the pros and cons of accessing a database out of a .Net class with a different number of database-users.
Are there any arguments against using just 1 mysql user like

```
new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=db;UID=alwaysthesameuser;PASSWORD=1234;")
```

or would it be better to use more users?

The application will be used by up to 100 users (who are working on clients) simultaneously. All querys are done on the server machine.

Is there anything I have to consider which could create problems later?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb to scale database connections set up a connection pool. Use the same user. We call this a application user. Connection pooling is a must in performance oriented database applications.

This of course assuming you are using a n tier model. Judging from your post it appears that you have a n tier model. If unsure go Google how to setup a connection pool in .net it is trivial from my  understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get better performance using a single "application user" database account, rather than lots of user accounts.

The big advantage is that you can make use of a connection pool, with connections that can be shared. With lots of separate accounts, you'd need lots of connection pools, one for each user account. What you want to avoid is "connection churning", that is, connecting and disconnecting from the database repeatedly, which limits performance and scalability.

There's also an administrative advantage (at least, on the database side), because you aren't having to create/lock/drop accounts and grant/revoke privileges. Not sure how much an effect there is with lots of rows in the `mysql.user`, `mysql.db`, etc. tables, but I think its unlikely that  lots of rows there would speed anything up.